# Building a word letter by letter

Tags: java

Been thinking about this and I can't seem to find a solution for this. The code allows to print the characters of a word letter by letter. This is fine, but if I want to build the word letter by letter. How is this possible?

For instance the word is `dogs` and output would be:

```
d
do
dog
dogs
```

*Source:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String word;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("insert your word");
    word = kb.nextLine();
    for (int k = 0; k< word.length(); k++)
    {
        System.out.println(word.charAt(k));
    }
    kb.close();
}
```

Once again sorry for the silly questions but I really can't see the solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example this code can help you.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= word.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(word.substring(0, i));
}
```

But really, in the future try to think yet another minute before asking a question...

Comment: `word.length()` you forgot parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to save the old characters that you've already printed. Try modifying your for loop thus:

```
String toPrint = "";
for (int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++){
    toPrint += word.charAt(k);
    System.out.println(toPrint);
}
```

Comment: It is better to use `StringBuilder` if you want to append parts to string in loop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with StringBuilder, but I will take a look.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you very much. How does the += word.charAt(k) work? first time i see the += being used

Comment: `a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b`. In other words, I'm adding the `charAt(a)` to the `toPrint` string.

Comment: @Snorrarcisco `toPrint += word.charAt(k)` behaves in the same way as `toPrint = toPrint + word.charAt(k)`.

Comment: @Snorrarcisco Also, we would appreciate it if you selected an answer! I'm quite partial to AlexR's.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the word to a char array with the to `charArray` method and then print the characters :

```
char [] word = "Dogs".toLowerCase().toCharArray();
int index = 1;
while(index <= word.length){
   for (int k = 0; k<index; k++){
    System.out.print(word[k]);
   }
   System.out.println();
   index++;
}
```

Output :

```
d
do
dog
dogs
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do a double loop.

```
for (int k = 0; k < word.length(); k++)
{

    for (int x = 0; x =< k; x++)
    {
        System.out.println(word.charAt(x));

    }
    System.out.println("");      //spacing
    k++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  String word;
  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("insert your word");
  word = kb.nextLine();
  for (int k = 0; k< word.length(); k++)
    {
      System.out.println(word.substring(0, k+1));
    }
    kb.close();
}
```

Hope this helps